# Initialise class template depending on another template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, types, class-template

This is what I have tried thus far:

Here is my code:

```
template<typename T1>
struct Foo 
{
    template<typename T2>
    using MyPair = std::pair<T1, T2>;
    using MyPairs = std::vector<MyPair>;

    Foo() 
    {
        //if T1 is an int, then I want T2 to be a double.
        //if T1 is a float, then I want T2 to be an int.
    }
};
```

I would like `T2` to be a `double` if `T1` is an `int`.
I would like `T2` to be an `int` if `T1` is a `float`.

How am I able to do this?

Comment: For example, `using T2 = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T1, int>, double, int>;`.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to solve this.

### Option - I

The simple way is to use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to define the alias for `T2`. In which if the `T1 == int` the `T2` will be `double`, **all other types**  the `T2` will be an alias for `int`. **([See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/89d3qG))**

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits> // std::conditional, std::is_same 

template<typename T1>
struct Foo /* final */
{
   static_assert(std::is_same<T1, int>::value || std::is_same<T1, float>::value, "NOT A VALID TYPE T1");

   using T2 = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T1, int>::value, double, int>::type;

   using MyPair = std::pair<T1, T2>;
};
```

If you want to restrict the instantiation of the class for other types, provide a  conditional instantiation of the class or a [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert).

---

### Option - II

You can use traits specialization to define the `T2` type. **([See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4b3jfj))**

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

// base template!
template <typename T1> struct helper_traits;

template <> //  when helper_traits<`T1 == int`>  then `T2 == double`
struct helper_traits<int> final {  using T2 = double; };

template <> //  when helper_traits<`T1 == float`>  then `T2 == int`
struct helper_traits<float>  final { using T2 = int; };

template<typename T1>
struct Foo /* final */
{
   using T2 = typename helper_traits<T1>::T2; // will select the proper one!

   using MyPair = std::pair<T1, T2>;
};
```

---

### Option - III

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), using the [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) you could decide which type to be returned in the function, and use it to know the type of `T2` as follows:
**([See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GMMcK3))**

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same_v

template<typename T1>
struct Foo /* final */
{
   template<typename Type>
   static constexpr auto typeHelper() noexcept
   {
      if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Type, int>)
         return double{};
      else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Type, float>) 
         return int{};
   }
   using T2 = decltype(Foo<T1>::typeHelper<T1>()); // will select the proper one!

   using MyPair = std::pair<T1, T2>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution hasn't a nested template but works as you expect:

```
template<typename T1,
         class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T1, int>::value || std::is_same<T1, float>::value>>
struct Foo {
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T1, int>::value, double, int>::type T2;
    using MyPair = std::pair<T1, T2>;
    using MyPairs = std::vector<MyPair>;
    MyPairs elements;
    Foo() {
        //if T1 is an int, then I want T2 to be a double.
        //if T1 is a float, then I want T2 to be an int.
        std::cout << typeid(T2).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> f;

    f.elements.push_back (std::make_pair(1.4, 2.3));

    std::cout << f.elements[0].first << ", " << f.elements[0].second << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
d
1, 2.3
```

Comment: `using T2 = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T1, int>, double, int>;`

Comment: @bipll yes, more C++ idiomatic. Voted +1.